# VBA Same excel file opening in 2 different places takes significantly different time

Tags: excel, vba, performance, file

I am opening an excel file in my code in 2 different places, with basically the same code. However, in one place it takes about 5 seconds and in the other 5+ MINUTES. I have tried opening in read-only mode in second place but no difference. Screen updating, calculation modes, events etc setting are all set to optimum and same for both procedures. Any ideas?

Procedure OK code:

```
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=wFolder + "\" + lstVals(i)
```

Procedure Not-OK code:

```
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=wFolder + "\" + lstVals(i)
```

Both procedures are also similar, taking in same input parameters, and are being invoked from the same form. Both are public Subs. Both open the file inside an if condition and a Do While Loop.
#OK basically opens this file as well as another, and adds the other file content to this file.
#Not-OK opens this file, does some editing to create a new excel which I save.

Time difference is in opening of the file, I have put in print statements before and after both invocations to narrow it down. I have also tried invoking both procedures in the same run, separately, one before/after the other, with other similar (different date and data) input files. Nothing makes any difference.

Comment: There's clearly something making a difference, but it's pretty difficult for us to know what that difference is.  For example is one of the files stored in a trusted location and the other not?  Or is it the same file in both cases?

Comment: It is a same file which is getting opened, so in the same location. I have to open it twice for different tasks. In one I need to add some info to the file to be able to process it later. In the second case I need to derive some info from this file for another task. So I open it, process and then store as a new, smaller file. Anyway, subsequent processing is irrelevant as it is the open statement which is taking different times.

Comment: I think without the full code to look at it's pretty much impossible to pin this down - you say both openings are happening under the same conditions, but that doesn't seem to be the case since there's a difference between the two cases.  Have you tried moving the file to a different location where opening time would be expected to be optimal (eg. local C drive) ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add a line like this:

DoEvents

before each invocation?  In one case there may be some uncompleted actions that need to occur before the workbook can be opened.

Also, I'm not a big fan of Workbooks.Open, I would prefer:

Dim wb as Workbook

set wb = ThisWorkbook.Application.Workbooks.Open …

This way you are explicitly setting an object to the workbook you are opening and can then reference that object when reading/writing to the workbook.  I've had troubles with other peoples' code when it was hard to decide which workbook was being referenced, which worksheet was the 'Active' sheet, etc.

The delay could be a result of the app pointing to a different active workbook or sheet in each case.  By explicitly associating the open workbook with and object you eliminate the ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks! I have a set thisWB = ActiveWorkbook right after the open.

Comment: Sorry for multiple responses... still coming to grips with comments here. The workbook being opened is exactly the same. I am even capturing the filename once and processing twice (depending on need). I also have a DoEvents right before the open since I am doing a screen refresh to see what I am starting to do. This showStatus is called before both opens.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, though still cannot understand what the problem is.

High level flow of both procedure is similar (to the WB open point) - define vars, turn off updates, assign initial values, start loop, EXTRA processing for NOT-OK, open file, process...

EXTRA processing is where I get a region-to-process-for as user input. I don't need this region for the OK procedure. Also, I need to grab the region separately for each file I process in NOT-OK procedure.

If I move the region-capture dialog AFTER the file open, everything works fine. File opens quickly, then I get the region and process.

Anyone has any idea why a simple dialog box based capture should cause file open to take long? Also, I am capturing this region for file processing in other procedures as well. It doesn't seem to be causing problems anywhere else.

Thanks to everyone who helped! My apologies if I should have mentioned the dialog box at the outset. It is a simple InputBox call which I use in multiple places and I didn't think it made a difference.